# Select particular field with condition satisfied in child in mongoDB using sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js

I am having a mongoDB collection and the JSON looks like

```
               [{
                  class : "I",
                  subject : "Maths",
                  students: [{
                             name : "John",
                             roll_no : "1001",
                             marks : "65",
                             is_passed : "true"
                             },
                            {
                             name : "Leo",
                             roll_no : "1002",
                             marks : "48",
                             is_passed : "false"
                             }]
                  }]
```

I am able to get the data using the command

```
My_Table_Name.find({}, {fields:{
                    'class' : 1,
                    'students':1
                   }
             })
             .populate('students',{
               select : ['name', 'is_passed']
             })
```

by this I can get the output as

```
    [{
     class : "I",
     students : [{
                   name : "John",
                   is_passed : "true"
                  },
                  {
                   name : "Leo",
                   is_passed : "false"
                  }]
     }]
```

but I need to get `is_passed` key only when it has `true` value,
my expected JSON is

```
   [{
     class : "I",
     students : [{
                   name : "John",
                   is_passed : "true"
                  },
                  {
                   name : "Leo"
                  }]
   }]
```

here in class I Leo has failed, so I do not need that field.

Please help to get through this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: My first thought is, if you want the other fields from records with `is_passed: false`, then why is it a problem to have that false value there? Is the result for your own use, or to submit somewhere with strict requirements, etc?